# Laravel Virtual Hosts for different Controllers

Tags: laravel, apache

I am trying to create virtual hosts for different controllers in my Laravel project.

For example

```
blog.example.com > http://www.example.com/public/blog/
forum.example.com > http://www.example.com/public/cms/forum/
```

Obviously /blog/ and /cms/forum/ are not actual folders in my /var/www/ directory, they are Laravel re-written "pretty URLs". The folder structure goes only as far as /var/www/LaravelProject/public/

So I can't put in my apache Virtual Host file this because */cms/forum/* does not exist as *folders*

```
DocumentRoot "/www/LaravelProject/public/cms/forum/"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use sub domain routing as well,
example :

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

check it out here [Sub-Domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing)

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!! Exactly what I was looking for!